# Is it possible to move the camera on a Google Map in Satellite mode?

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

In an Android app I'm trying to simulate a flyover of an area of land.
I can quite happily zoom into the start and animate the camera to the final point.
This works fine when it's a MAP_TYPE of normal.
Change it to a MAP_TYPE of SATELLITE it merely pauses for a while before displaying the final location. 
Any way of getting the camera to animate from to start to end in Satellite view, I dont mind having to do some preload of images if necessary.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes you can. 
What you need to do is let the looper finish drawing, then do your camera move.
So, a typical step by step animation would be a bit like this.

```
Move camera to position
When animation completes (onFinish)...
    Start new thread, delay for a second or two, then on UI thread do camera 
    move.(onFinish of this animation, start new thread and do another camera 
    move. etc etc
```